# Error running CoffeeScript in Sublime Text 2

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2

I am new to both CoffeeScript and Sublime Text 2, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I try to compile a CoffeeScript test file in Sublime, I get the following error message:

```
    [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    [cmd:  [u'coffee', u'-c', u'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.coffee']]
    [dir:  C:\Users\username\Desktop]
    [path: $HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm]

[Finished]
```

Here are my build settings in commands:

```
    {
    "path": "$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH",
    "cmd": ["coffee","-c","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.coffee, source.litcoffee, source.coffee.md"
}
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the following code in the build file:

```
{
   "cmd": [ "coffee", "-m", "-c", "$file" ],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.coffee, source.litcoffee, source.coffee.md",

   "windows":
   {
      "shell": true
   }
}
```